# How to add different css files conditionally on angular 2 component?

Tags: angular

My app uses different languages and some of them are right-to-left. I have two separate css files; one for LTR and the other for RTL.

how can i conditionally add a css file on component?

I found a solution for this problem(refer to answer on [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4685#issuecomment-279746337)), but this is not a good solution.

As you will see below, my code to solve this problem is here.

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngw-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isRtl:Boolean;

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) localeId) {
    if(localeId == "fa-IR") {
      require('style-loader!./app.component.rtl.css');
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

typings.d.ts

```
declare var require: any;
```

**What I'm looking for:**

theme.ts

```
interface Theme {
  url: string;
  rel: string;
  media: string;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngw-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: AppComponentThemeProvider
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

app.component.theme.ts

```
export class AppComponentThemeProvider {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private localeId) {
  }

  getThemes() {
    let themes = [<Theme>{url:'./app.component.css'}];

    if(this.localeId == 'fa-IR') {
      themes.push(<Theme>{url: './app.component.rtl.css'})
    }

    return themes;
  }
}
```

Comment: add more information to post

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not easily achievable in Angular and also, the way the browsers behave is that as soon as you download the CSS , they'll be there till you close the browser or you delete the style, which is tricky.

The easiest and safest option would be to namespace the css files and the conditionally add that namespace to your body.

LTR styles :

```
 app-root.LTR{
    all your LTR styles will be here
 }
```

RTL styles :

```
  app-root.RTL{
    all your RTL styles will be here
 }
```

and then in your `app-root` component :

```
@Component({
    selector:'app-root'

})

export class AppComponent{

      @HostBinding('[class.RTL]') get language(){


      if  it should be RTL   return true;

     }

      @HostBinding('[class.LTR]') get language(){


         if  it should be LTR   return true;

     }


// I'm not sure how would you determine which language is it gonna be, but it's normally a parameter in the url , so you can use Angular's router to detect that and flesh out the above if conditions

}
```